# What's the name of this spectrum analyser input connector (Agilent E4402B)?

Tags: connector, spectrum-analyzer

Here's a photograph of the input connector and one of the attachments that came with it (which is this unknown connector to SMA converter).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are 50\$\Omega\$ [Type N](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1931349.pdf) connectors. Typical on Spectrum Analyzers.

The definitive standard is MIL-STD-348.

Comment: Type N is used because it's a really nice controlled impedance connector, and good up into the GHz range -- a plain old BNC is only good up to about 400MHz or so.  You don't want to be doing tests and worrying about your connector integrity.